# Create two 0-d tensors x and y randomly selected from -1 and 1

Tags: tensorflow

```
x = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
y = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
def f1():return x+y
def f2():return x-y
def f3():return 0

r = tf.case({tf.less(x,y): f1, tf.greater(x,y): f2}, default = f3,exclusive 
= True)
```

this is the question : Return x + y if x < y, x - y if x > y, 0 otherwise,i seem to be getting int object has not attribute 'name'.any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `f3` return float instead of integer.

This works for me:

```py
x = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
y = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
def f1():return x+y
def f2():return x-y
def f3():return 0.0

r = tf.case({tf.less(x,y): f1, tf.greater(x,y): f2}, default=f3, 
            exclusive=True)
```

**Edit:**

While the code above works with recent Tensorflow to make it work with older versions it is required to make `f3` return `Tensor` as well.

```py
x = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
y = tf.random_uniform([], -1, 1)
def f1():return x+y
def f2():return x-y
def f3():return tf.constant(0.0)

r = tf.case({tf.less(x,y): f1, tf.greater(x,y): f2}, default=f3, 
            exclusive=True)
```

Comment: dm0_ , i tried it now im getting,float object has no attribute name

Comment: @DecentMakeover, what TF version do you use? That code works with TF 1.1.0-rc2. Please try replacing `0.0` with `tf.constant(0.0)`.

Comment: Thank you so much,i forgot to include the constant!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your random numbers in [`tf.sign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sign) function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.sign(tf.random_uniform((10,), -1, 1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(x)
```

and you will get something like: `[ 1.  1.  1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.]`. It works because:

> Returns an element-wise indication of the sign of a number.
>
> y = sign(x) = -1 if x < 0; 0 if x == 0 or tf.is_nan(x); 1 if x > 0.